# A boy can regenerate, so demons eat him for years. He also rips off an arm to use as a sword

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character's body regrows limbs instantly. He was kidnapped by demons after they learn this, so they can have a steady supply of food without any trouble. Afterwards, he escapes and trains to fight demons. He also likes to rip off his arm and use it as a sword.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the manhwa, ***[Monster Hunter](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/osk97c4/new-army)***.

> The monsters take everything away from a boy and keep him captive as their food.
> He grunts his teeth and seeks revenge, but the human power has fallen short to beat the monsters.
> At that moment, a monster hunter appears…

Some monsters kill the protagonist's family, but discover that they can't kill him since he keeps regenerating, so they hold him prisoner for years and use him as a self-replenishing food source. He's subsequently freed by a monster hunter, who teaches him how to fight monsters, and in one scene, he rips off one of his own arms and uses it as a sword.

[image] [image]

Comment: He "grunts" his teeth... is that a typo for "grits"

Comment: @James K - Probably. I suspect that that synopsis may've written by someone whose first language wasn't English.